# Uninformed parameter in a PHP function

Tags: php, function

I have this simple function in PHP:

```
function formatDateTime($lang) {
    if(!isset($lang)) { $lang == 'en'; }

    if($lang == 'fr') { ... }
    if($lang == 'en') { ... }
}
```

Depending on my needs, I sometimes call this function like this:

```
function formatDateTime('en');
```

or sometimes like this (without an argument):

```
function formatDateTime('');
```

When I call the function with an argument (i.e.: `en`), it works. But if I do not pass any argument it can't enter into the condition `if(!isset($lang)) { ... }`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just use default value for the parameter `function formatDateTime($lang = null) { ...` and change your condition, remove the `isset`

Comment: To call a function `foo` with no argument, you write: `foo()`.  You do not prepend with the word function.  Calling like this: `foo('')`, would pass an empty string as the first argument.

Comment: `isset` won't work here, as the variable is definitly set through the method's argument list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set a default value for your parameter and then you need to correct the default language assignment from '==' to  '='. Here is how your function needs to look:

```
function formatDateTime($lang = null) {
    if(!isset($lang) || empty($lang)) { $lang = 'en'; }

    if($lang == 'fr') { echo 'fr'; }
    if($lang == 'en') { echo 'en'; }
}
```

Calling the function:

```
formatDateTime(''); // prints 'en'
formatDateTime(); // prints 'en'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you want a default argument value of 'en' for $lang:

```
function formatDateTime($lang = 'en') {
}
```